# How to sum specific information w/ multiple criteria including dates from form submission

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I have a sheet that is linked to a google form so when a person submits the form, the information is populated into the sheet automatically with a timestamp, ex.`1/17/2020 17:26:16`. I'm trying to sum information based on multiple criteria and one is to only pull a full days worth of data but the formula is reading time as well and so I keep yielding 0.

For example, here is some data

```
1/8/2020 17:38:49   Danny   PM  Beetlejuice on Broadway 1144
1/8/2020 17:38:49   Danny   PM  Oklahoma! on Broadway   1181
1/8/2020 17:38:49   Danny   PM  Oklahoma! on Broadway   1000.5
1/8/2020 12:47:18   Jeff    PM  To Kill a Mockingbird   1675
1/8/2020 12:48:19   Jeff    PM  Jagged Little Pill      2390
```

On another tab I'm trying to calculate how much was spent by each person on this day. This new tab is looking at a persons shift and name to sumifs their spend:

```
=SUMIFS('Form Responses 1'!$E:$E,'Form Responses 1'!$D:$D,B$5,'Form Responses 1'!$B:$B,$A9,'Form Responses 1'!$C:$C,$B$2)
```

I don't believe you'll need to know what each piece in this current code means since I just need to add to it for it to read a range of dates and narrow down to one day.

I've tried adding the date range `'Form Responses 1'!$E:$E` and having the criterion be the desired date filled in `B2` but this is when it is reading for an exact match of the time from the range which is not going to work since I don't want it to read the time. I want to find a solution that won't involve having to manually update the submission data each time.

I've included a sample sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mOZ5AHMh4I_QYA1hrShr0cQ3PaogXpsBd5FbCIzqJ3E/edit?usp=sharing) so whoever wants to try and tackle this can better see what it is I'm working with. In the review tab I have my current formula not specifying date and next to it the same but trying to specify the date.

Thank you in advance. My brain is a scattered mess so I hope everything makes sense.

Comment: If you make your sheet editable, instead of View only, the experts here can test and demo more easily.

Comment: Big YIKES! Thank you for pointing that out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all records for the specified day to be included, you must use the `>=` and `<=` operators.

Something like this:

```
=SUMIFS('Form Responses 1'!$E:$E,
  'Form Responses 1'!$B:$B, $A6,
  'Form Responses 1'!$C:$C, $B$2,
  'Form Responses 1'!$A:$A, ">="&$B$1,
  'Form Responses 1'!$A:$A, "<="&$B$1+1)
```

Comment: Thank you! As per usual for me, I simply switched the the signs but could not see it!
">=" for B1+1 and "<=" for B1. Thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [accepted correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63928277/1527780), you could also try the following [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) formula so you can get everything with **just one formula instead of 5**.

```
=IFERROR({QUERY(A:E,"select B, sum(E) where not A='' and C='"&H2&"' group by B label B 'Runner Name', sum(E) 'Total Spend' ",1), 
          QUERY(A:E,"select    sum(E) where not A='' and C='"&H2&"' and todate(A)=date '"&text(H1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by B label sum(E) 'Totals per day' ",1)},
         "No data")
```

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

By using `todate(A)` we **extract the date value from a timestamp**.

The **big advantage** of using a single query is that -since you use the **data from a form**- your **results will auto update** as new answers come through.

*Please feel free to ask if you need further information.*

Answer (score 0):

Another query that should work for you i've left on the new MK.Help tab in cell A5.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({INT('Form Responses 1'!A:A),'Form Responses 1'!B1:E},"select Col2,SUM(Col5) where Col1="&B1&" and Col3='"&B2&"' group by Col2 order by SUM(Col5) desc label SUM(Col5)'Total'"))
```

Agree with the previous poster that a query is the way to go since it'll autopopulate.  Also it allows you to display the table in any order you like.  I chose to sort by the total with the highest totals at the top.